# MiKTeX pre-release: Possible bug(s) in fbb/ETbb (e.g., ETbb’s swashQ incompatible with \textit and fbb/ETbb with footmisc’s option symbol)

Tags: footmisc, bugs

**Edit 2020-07-14:** This problem is now also reported as [issue #587](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/587) on MiKTeX’s repository on GitHub.

## Remark: As of 2020-07-13, the problem occurs only for the pre-release MiKTeX distribution, so only beta packages are affected.

The following example:

### MWE 1:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[swashQ]{fbb} % No error.
%\usepackage{ETbb} % No error.
\usepackage[swashQ]{ETbb} % Error when using with \textit{…}.

\begin{document}
    Quest. % No error.
    \textit{Test}. % Error when using with \usepackage[swashQ]{ETbb}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output for fbb]

fails with error `Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\⟨User⟩\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log` and the contents of the mentioned log are:

```
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - this process (2904) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode texstudio_JeXOrj.tex
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex.core - Read operation failed.
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: path="", read="0", n="1"
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:255
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Read operation failed.
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="", read="0", n="1"
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Line: 255
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - this process (2904) finishes with exit code 1
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.tex
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.pdf
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.aux
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.log
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Users\⟨User⟩\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/vf/public/etbb\ETbb-Italic-tlf-swash-t1.vf"
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - this process (23036) started by 'texstudio' with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode texstudio_JeXOrj.tex
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex.core - Read operation failed.
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: path="", read="0", n="1"
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:255
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Read operation failed.
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="", read="0", n="1"
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
⟨time⟩ FATAL pdflatex - Line: 255
⟨time⟩ INFO  pdflatex - this process (23036) finishes with exit code 1
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.tex
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.aux
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.pdf
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: texstudio_JeXOrj.log
⟨time⟩ WARN  miktex.core - still open: "C:\Users\⟨User⟩\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/vf/public/etbb\ETbb-Italic-tlf-swash-t1.vf"
```

Commenting out `\textit{Test}` as well as switching `\usepackage[swashQ]{ETbb}` to `\usepackage{ETbb}` or to `\usepackage[swashQ]{fbb}` removes the problem. So there is probably a conflict between `swashQ` option of `ETbb` and some internal macros of `\textit`. I have no ideas how to investigate this matter further, but maybe someone of TeX.SX community could help to eliminate this problem.

---

## Edit 2020-07-14:

A similar error occurs when using either `fbb` or `ETbb` (without any options) with footnotes supplied by `footmisc` package with option `symbol`. An illustrative MWE is below. It also works well on the stable MiKTeX and fails on thr pre-release.

### MWE 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\usepackage{fbb} % Error when using with \footnote{…} of footmisc with option symbol.
%\usepackage{ETbb} % Error when using with \footnote{…} of footmisc with option symbol.

\begin{document}
    Test% No error.
    \footnote{Test.}. % Error for \usepackage{fbb} or \usepackage{ETbb}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: works ok for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Well, I forgot that I was working on the pre-release and thus did not try this on the stable version. I’ll update the question – the MWE works well on the regular MiKTeX, but it still fails on beta, so there is probably some bug (and probably more of them, as I just found) hiding in the upcoming distribution.

Comment: If you have a document that works fine with release MikTeX, but errors with pre-release MikTeX I strongly recommend you report this at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues with as much detail as possible. It's quite likely that the problem is with a MikTeX component in that case, especially considering the low-level error message you got here.

Comment: I reported this on MiKTeX’s repository on GitHub as [issue #587](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/587).